# Spring MVC / Security - "Store is closed" Security Filter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC webapp that uses Spring Security.  I want to add "Store is closed" functionality - i.e.  if I set the store to be closed, regardless of where the user tries to navigate on my site they will end up on the page saying "Store is closed".

I have implemented a Security Filter as follows (and can wire it in fine):

```
public class ClosedFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(storeIsClosed()) {
        //do something useful here
    }else {
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
            }

}

}
```

But am unsure what to put in the "//do something useful here" bit.  I have tried:

```
throw new StoreIsClosedException();  //extends RuntimeException
```

but I can't then map my exception to my view.  I also tried

```
response.redirect("myClosedView");
```

with no luck.  What I want is something conceptually like:

```
   return new ModelAndView("closed");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe look at setting http response code of 503, server temporaraly unavalible, then create an error page for the 503 which says closed. Maybe someone can answer with the exact code. I'm on my phone.

Comment: thanks for the details, it inspired me to the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with a solution, I changed my filter to:

```
public class ClosedFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (isClosed()) {
        final String path = req.getContextPath()+"/closed.do";
        if(!path.equals(req.getRequestURI())) {
            response.sendRedirect(path);
            return;
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, response);
}


}
```

and then added this to my security.xml

```
<intercept-url pattern="/closed.do*" access="permitAll"/>
```